# Implementing an enum field for peewee.Model

Tags: python, python-3.x, enum, orm

I implemented an enum field class `EnumField` inheriting from `peewee.CharField`.
The reason that I use a character-based field is that I require human-readability of the enumeration values on the database level.

I currently use the funcion `is_enum` to detemine whether the provided enum constraint is an `enum.Enum`.
Knowing this is important, since `enum.Enum` instances need to be translated, unlinke `set`s of strings, back and forth between the enum value and string value.
I'd especially like to improve this translation.

```
class InvalidEnumerationValue(ValueError):
    """Indicates that an invalid enumeration value has been specified."""

    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__('Invalid enum value: "{}".'.format(value))
```

---

```
def is_enum(obj):
    """Determines whether the object is an enum.Enum."""

    try:
        return issubclass(obj, Enum)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

---

```
class EnumField(peewee.CharField):
    """CharField-based enumeration field."""

    def __init__(self, enum, *args, max_length=None, null=None, **kwargs):
        """Initializes the enumeration field with the possible values.

        :enum: The respective enumeration.
        :max_length: Ignored.
        :null: Ignored.
        """
        super().__init__(*args, max_length=max_length, null=null, **kwargs)
        self.enum = enum

    @property
    def enum(self):
        """Returns the enumeration values."""
        return self._enum

    @enum.setter
    def enum(self, enum):
        """Sets the enumeration values."""
        if is_enum(enum):
            self._enum = enum
        else:
            self._enum = set(enum)

    @property
    def values(self):
        """Yields appropriate database values."""
        if is_enum(self.enum):
            for item in self.enum:
                yield item.value
        else:
            for value in self.enum:
                yield value

    @property
    def max_length(self):
        """Derives the required field size from the enumeration values."""
        return max(len(value) for value in self.values if value is not None)

    @max_length.setter
    def max_length(self, max_length):
        """Mockup to comply with super class' __init__."""
        if max_length is not None:
            LOGGER.warning(
                'Parameter max_length=%s will be ignored since it '
                'is derived from enumeration values.', str(max_length))

    @property
    def null(self):
        """Determines nullability by enum values."""
        return any(value is None for value in self.values)

    @null.setter
    def null(self, null):
        """Mockup to comply with super class' __init__."""
        if null is not None:
            LOGGER.warning(
                'Parameter null=%s will be ignored since it '
                'is derived from enumeration values.', str(null))

    def db_value(self, value):
        """Coerce enumeration value for database."""
        if is_enum(value):
            if value in self.enum:
                return value.value
        elif value in self.values:
            return value

        raise InvalidEnumerationValue(value)

    def python_value(self, value):
        """Coerce enumeration value for python."""
        if is_enum(self.enum):
            for item in self.enum:
                if item.value == value:
                    return item
        elif value in self.values:
            return value

        raise InvalidEnumerationValue(value)
```

Comment: A [previous version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/177693/51621) sadly had some undetected bugs that made the actual code to be considered *broken*.